# Can't seem to figure out why the DIV isn't applying to entire section, PHP/HTML DIV issue

Tags: php, html

thanks for assisting.

I'm having an issue in which my DIV class named box-2 is only applying itself to the title of the section, even though I closed it around the entire code. I'm very new to PHP, so I'm wondering if there is something I'm overlooking.

```
<div class="box-2 shadow">
<?php if (get_field('highlights')) { //Sub speciality ?>

    <div itemprop="Restuarant Highlights">
        <h3 class="content-title">Highlights</h3>

            <ul>
            <?php $terms = get_field('highlights'); ?>
            <?php foreach ($terms as $term){ ?>
            <li><div class="sl-highlights"><span class="icon-ok-circled"><?php echo $term->name; ?></span></div></li>

            <?php } ?>
            </ul>
       </div>
    </div>

<div class="clearboth"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

I need the box-2 class to be applied to everything, as it spaces out the entire section for me.

**EDIT:** This pulls the data from a taxonomy, and displays it like:

Bananas Apples Pears Lemons Grapes
Peaches Strawberrys

Here is the CSS:

```
.box-2 {
width: 100%;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.05);
margin-bottom: 7px;
padding: 12px 0 3px 0;
}

.sl-highlights {
float: left;
margin-right: 4%;
font-size: 14px;
min-width: 135px;
line-height: 25px;
}

.content-title {
font-size: 18px;
color: #444;
padding-bottom: 9px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: 'HelveticaNeue','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

Thank you very much for any and all help!

Comment: Do you have a closing `</div>` that you didn't include? If not, that could be your issue.

Comment: Might help to see what CSS you're trying to apply. The markup looks correct.

Comment: Let's see the output HTML, as generated by the PHP. That might help show up the problem.

Comment: (Also: where's the closing `}` for the first `if`?)

Comment: @Waxen I scanned through the entire page a few times, all of the divs are closed.

Comment: @MattGibson Not sure... The code seems to work for pulling the data I need, what do you think the issue is? I'm not very competent with PHP at this point. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried setting a min-height for .box-2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you apply a float style to an element, you remove it from the normal document flow; basically, the element doesn't reserve the space it normally would. Since that's what normally defines the height of it's container, the container tends to collapse to the height of the next element that *is* in the normal flow.

In your case, since all of the elements that have content are floated, `box-2` collapses to a zero height. If you want it to still contain the floated elements, add an `overflow: auto;` rule to `.box-2`.

You can simplify your markup a bit by eliminating the `<div>` elements that currently have the `sl-highlights` class and instead apply the class to the `<li>` elements. I'd probably add a `display: block` rule too, since technically it's invalid to have a block-level element (the `<h3>` tags) inside an inline element (the `<li>` element).

Comment: Wonderful! This was exactly the issue, I also applied all of your suggested changes. Thank you so much for the help!